# ShellScript, any better ways to 'find' the files with specific name and date?

Tags: linux, shell

I got a question on the Linux and Shellscript, i know it can`t to get the file from the created date, only the modified dates, but how about , if I got the created date on the files name?

For example, now there are folder which includes some files:

```
ABCADD01-20230801
ABCADD01-20230802
ABCADD01-20230803
ABCADD01-20230804
ABCADD02-20230801
ABCADD02-20230802
ABCAEE01-20230801
ABCAEE01-20230802
ABCAEE01-20230803
ABCAFF01-20230801
ABCAGG01-20230802
```

And I need to find the files name is "`ABCADD`" and the creation date is "2 days ago or earlier", and zip those files. Today is `20230804`

I got an idea is using two for loop:
first loop is finding the files name included "`ABCADD`", second loop is finding the creation dated is two days ago.

```bash
# Get the date for two days ago
two_days_ago=$(date -d "2 days ago" +%Y%m%d)

# Find the "ABCADD" files that were last modified two days ago, zip them
for file in $(find . -name 'ABCADD*' -type f ); do
    for file in $(find . -name '*$two_days_ago' -type f ); do
    echo "Zipping $file"
    gzip "$file"
    done
done
```

The expected final results should be

```
ABCADD01-20230801
ABCADD01-20230802 
ABCADD02-20230801
ABCADD02-20230802
```

however, i can't get the "two days ago or earlier" and only able to get the specific day which is `20230802`, and there are still some bugs. any better ways?

Comment: Why not `-name 'ABCADD*$two_days_ago'`? Why a loop with a nested find? (the loop will break with blanks or newlines in your file names). Can you check the modification time of the files (`-ctime`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### UPDATE

Here's a possible solution in the form of `date; find -exec awk | xargs gzip`:

```bash
two_days_ago=$(date -d '2 days ago' +%Y%m%d)

find . -name 'ABCADD*-20[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' \
       -exec awk -v max="$two_days_ago" '
           BEGIN {
               for ( i = 1; i < ARGC; i++ ) {
                   n = split(ARGV[i], a, "-");
                   if ( a[n] <= max)
                       printf("%s%c", ARGV[i], 0);
               }
               exit;
           }
       ' {} + |
xargs -0 gzip
```

Comment: But there has a problem,  system date is 20230804, 
if I use 

```
find . -name "ABCADD*-$two_days_ago" -exec gzip {} \;
```
I only can get the files created date is 20230802,
can`t get all the files which created  2 days before

Comment: @Chuuuuuu46 20230802 is all files created 2 days before. Or do you mean "2 days before _or earlier_"? That's not easily possible only by name. Is it not possible to filter on `-ctime +2`?

Comment: ohh yes, what I mean is "2 days before or earlier".  And -ctime +2 only to find the modified time. So, there are no another way to find the created dates is "2 days before or earlier"? by using the name?